# What does this bash command involving "softcore-make-write" do?

Tags: embedded

I need to understand what is happening in the following command line.

```
/bin/softcore-make-write /config/cfg.cid /config/logics/step.st
```

This script is running on an embedded Linux.
What I know so far is that the content of step.st is changing the logic state of some digital outputs of the equipment. cfg.cid is the configuration file for the OS.
Any thoughts would be highly appreciated.

Comment: (Context for readers: This question was originally tagged bash). This isn't part of bash. Only someone who knows your `softcore-make-write` command can answer this question (in a way you're likely to find useful).

Comment: We could tell you exactly what bash is doing when given that command, but since all bash does is run `execl("/bin/softcore-make-write", "/bin/softcore-make-write", "/config/cfg.cid", "/config/logics/step.st", NULL)` in a subshell and wait for it to exit, that's not a very useful answer.

Comment: Thanks Charles. My problem in understanding this is more related to the syntax of the command line.. I'm not really interested in how softcore-make-write deal with the information. For example, can I say that step.st and cfg.cid are both commands to softcore-make-write? or step.st is a command to cfg.cid and then cfg.cid is a command to softcore-make-write? Do you know what mean?

Comment: That's specific to how `softcore-make-write` chooses to interpret its arguments. It's part of that program, and can't be answered without knowing how that program works.

Comment: ...which is to say, *both* `/config/cfg.cid` and `/config/logics/step.st` are arguments to the program `softcore-make-write`. What meaning those arguments have is 100% an attribute of that program. (Which is basically what I said before, in my second comment: The shell spawns a child process which `exec`s the `softcore-make-write` program, with the other strings as command-line parameters to that program).

Comment: Now is clear to me. Thank you Charles!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the shell is given the command line:

```
/bin/softcore-make-write /config/cfg.cid /config/logics/step.st
```

...that command is split into three words, parsed as a single simple external command. In executing that command, behavior is equivalent to the following (which may reflect some minor simplifications, but not ones which materially impact your question):

- The original shell [`fork()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)s off a child process.
- The child process calls [`execl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)`("/bin/softcore-make-write", "/bin/softcore-make-write", "/config/cfg.cid", "/config/logics/step.st", NULL)`, replacing itself in-memory with a copy of `/bin/softcore-make-write` with its `main()` function passed an `argc` of 3 and an `argv` of `char[][]{"/bin/softcore-make-write", "/config/cfg.cid", "/config/logics/step.st", NULL}`.
- The original shell uses [`waitpid()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) to wait for that child process to complete.
- The original shell sets `$?` to the exit status returned by `waitpid()`.

In the case where no error handling is needed, that's all the shell does -- everything else is done by `softcore-make-write`, and thus requires knowledge of its operation.

The shell does not know or care anything about the strings passed as arguments -- they could be filenames, but they could be anything else as well; they're simply passed through for `softcore-make-write` to handle as it sees fit.